# What is the file path of the main page (home) of a Magento store?

Tags: php, magento

I need to locate the file that manages the main page of my online store developed with Magento (which would be the index.html). I just need to change a link, and I've used Firebug shows that the file i need to edit is "misitioweb.com" (the main page) but the document itself does not appear in the ftp. The initial page consists of a bunch of XML, and PHP's PHTML. If someone wants to see the address page is http://peluches-cel.com and only want to change the destination URL of the link "Peluche del mes". I have used the help of Magento to show "Help template route" and I downloaded the 4 files that are more likely to manage that area of the page, but I can not find the part where specify the destination URL of the link. I have always worked with HTML or PHP separately (I have little experience with PHP) and I find it very difficult to understand how Magento builds each website. If someone could give me a little hint on how to achieve change that link would you do me very happy, it took a long time trying it on my own and looking online but can not find how to do any guestbook or forum that explains how to work well with Magento, in my language, there are hardly any documentation on Magento, so I decided to try my luck in this forum and I've read on several pages that involves many professionals in the e-commerce. Thanks in advance to all who devote their time to read my question.

Comment: You need to use URl Redirect Management in magento admin under catlog menu..please refer here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation Chanz, but what you show me has nothing to do with what I want. I need to change a link at the home of the url: "peluches-cel.com" which is a Magento. How do I get the code which changes the href link? In Magento, there is not an index.html.......

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want.

But if you want to change the base URL, you can do that by accessing database via phpMyAdmin, find the table core_config_data and change the URL in the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not the url of the page, but the url of a link. Try clicking on "Peluche del mes" and see what comes out, gives access to http://www.peluches-cel.com/peluche-del-mes, I want access to http://www.peluches-cel.com/oso-tiziano-2col-40cm directly. The problem is NOT EXISTS peluches-cel.com/oso-tiziano-2col-40cm page on FTP, to be done in PHP there are different functions that are responsible for creating it at the time of the request I need to change the link to "Peluche del mes", if you see with firebug or any other source code analyzer, the source code of the page you will see that line 146 is managed that link, but I can not directly access the code ¿do you understand me? through an ftp client no such file or html as php magento works with the model view controller, that's my problem. Thank you again.